# WSS Support in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am verifying the Websocket support in WSO2 API manager for one of my requirement. By default, WSO2 API Manager provides the options for configuring "WS" protocol and able to access it. But I couldn't find any configuration for "WSS" protocol support.

Is there any limitation in WSO2 API manager or is there any documentation available?

Thanks,
Sow

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket support is available by default in WSO2 API Manager. Related transport configurations should be available inside the axis2.xml configuration file. You can find related documentation in the WSO2 API Manager documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+a+WebSocket+API

Comment: Hi, I was also referring the same url to enable Websocket. but the challenge I faced as secured web socket which is WSS. I have configured WSS configuration in axis2.xml. but still no lock

Answer (score 0):

When using wss endpoint, we were able to observe some errors and we were able to get rid of the errors with the following approach.

Please include the following parameter in the SecureWebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml file which resides in the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/inbound-endpoints directory.

TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
Also, please remove the following parameters from the same SecureWebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml file if the following parameters(wss.ssl.trust.store.file and wss.ssl.trust.store.pass) exist in the file.

repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
wso2carbon
Please use the following sample web socket client to try out and run the WSS client. Please change the variable carbonKeyStoreLocation to point to <API-M_HOME>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks. Note that port for the WSS API is 8099.
You can download the WSS client in the following WSO2 official documentation under the WSS Support section. (In the second step.)[1] Further please change the access token, web socket endpoint and the carbonKeyStoreLocation with your one to try out the scenario.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+a+WebSocket+API